# Question On T-Statistic in Regression Example

Tags: regression, t-test, standard-error, causality

I am reading through *The Effect: An Introduction to Research Design and Causality* and in chapter 13 on regression, there is a code example of calculating regression that I am not fully grasping. It is using a dataset for inspection scores of restaurants with features such as the year of inspection and number of restaurant locations. Below is the snippet before the code and the code. My questions are:

- I am not following what is happening for the t-test, despite the comments in the code. What is happening and why?
- It mentions the calculation being done for specific value of *NumberofLocations* and that a standard error on the effect is being produced. I am not seeing a specific value being referenced. How is that being done and why?

Thank you!!!

> First, we’ll do a regression with a polynomial in it. Then, we’ll calculate the effect of *NumberofLocations* for a given value of the variable in such a way that also gives us a standard error on the effect at that value.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from stargazer.stargazer import Stargazer
from causaldata import restaurant_inspections
df = restaurant_inspections.load_pandas().data

# Use I() to insert calculations of your variables
# and ** to square
m1 = sm.ols(formula = "'inspection_score ~ 
  NumberofLocations + 
  I(NumberofLocations**2) + 
  Year"', data = df).fit()

# m1.summary() would do here, but if we wanted
# to write to file we could extend Stargazer...
Stargazer([m1])

# Use t_test to test linear combinations of coefficients
# be sure to test them against 0 to get the appropriate result
# coef is the estimate here, std err the SE.
# We know this is the right equation to use because we know
# the derivative - we need to figure that out first
m1.t_test('NumberofLocations + 2*I(NumberofLocations ** 2)*100 = 0')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question:

1. What's happening in the $t$-test is as follows. Let $k$ be the `NumberofLocations` variable, and $\ell$ be the `inspection_score`. The linear regression call to `sm.ols` is modeling $\ell\sim k+k^2+\text{year}.$ That means the `sm.ols` call will return a number of things, of which three are the previously unknown coefficients $\beta_k, \beta_{k^2},$ and $\beta_{\text{year}}.$ The $t$-test on the last line, then, is testing the hypothesis
   $$\beta_k+200\,\beta_{k^2}=0.$$
   This sort of hypothesis testing is a standard kind of test you can do with regression coefficients. See Section 11.12 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer. The $t$-statistic associated with the test we can write down if we introduce the "linear combination" vector
   $$a=\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\200 \\0\end{matrix}\right],$$
   so that the test is testing
   $$a^T\beta=0,$$
   where
   $$\beta=\left[\begin{matrix}\beta_k\\ \beta_{k^2}\\ \beta_{\text{year}}\end{matrix}\right].$$
   Then if $X$ is the model matrix (usually prepend a column of zeros to the $x$ data), you would have (in this case, since you're testing against zero)
   $$t=\frac{a^T\beta}{\mathbf{S}\sqrt{a^T(X^TX)^{-1}a}}.$$
2. I think this question is really about the `I()` notation, which also happens in R. When you're doing a linear regression using this notation, also known as the Wilkinson-Rogers notation, if you want to introduce functions of a particular explanatory variable, you have to wrap it in `I()`, or you will get unexpected results. Try doing the regression without the `I()` call, and you will see something different. "The function `I()` ensures that the argument is evaluated (in this case squaring) rather than interpreted as part of the model formula." - adapted from *Linear Models with R, 2nd Ed.,* by Faraway, p. 39.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thank you